# Is it safe to call an async function during lambda nodejs init?

Tags: aws-lambda

I would like to know whether it is safe to make HTTP(S) requests during the `Init` phase of a NodeJS Lambda function. In particular, I would like to make calls to AWS SSM [`GetParameter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html) using [@aws-sdk/client-ssm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-ssm) or AWS KMS [`Decrypt`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Decrypt.html) using [@aws-sdk/client-kms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-kms) to load secrets that will be used within the handler.

I have found one example online of someone creating a `Promise` outside of the handler and then `await`ing it within the handler ([Async Initialisation of a Lambda Handler](https://serverlessfirst.com/fff-function-initialisation/)), but I haven’t seen this approach endorsed in the official [Lambda sample applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-samples.html). None of the official examples do any work outside of the handler.

According to [AWS Lambda execution environment: Lambda execution environment lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html#runtimes-lifecycle), “Lambda freezes the execution environment when the runtime and each extension have completed and there are no pending events.” [AWS Lambda Runtime API: Next invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-api.html#runtimes-api-next) elaborates on the `http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next` endpoint, “Do not set a timeout on the GET call. Between when Lambda bootstraps the runtime and when the runtime has an event to return, the runtime process may be frozen for several seconds.” I take this to mean that Lambda will signal the process with `SIGSTOP` at the time of the `next` call if [Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/) is enabled as well as between requests.

In addition, when I look at lambcli’s [lambda sources](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) (`docker run -it --rm lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x cat /var/runtime/Runtime.js`), I see that `scheduleIteration` calls `setImmediate(() => this.handleOnce()…)` which calls `this.client.nextInvocation` so I don’t see a way to delay the `nextInvocation` call.

Questions:

1. In the Lambda nodejs runtime, is it possible to perform a HTTP request and await its response entirely within the `Function init` phase?
2. If you make a request outside of the handler, will the server time out the connection, resulting in Connection Closed errors when the handler awaits the response?
3. Is there a better recommended way to perform one-time initialization of secrets?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the same challenge myself.

Comment: @CraigEdwards For a NodeJS Lambda without ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig, I think it’s ok to initiate async operations outside the handler, but it probably doesn’t speed anything up since there’s already an event to handle. For a NodeJS Lambda with ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig, I think it’s best to avoid making any requests before the handler unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not able to fully answer all of your questions, I found this blog post that describes a possible solution: https://barker.tech/aws-lambda-nodejs-async-init-88b5c24af567

So in the end, the answers would be:

1. Yes, it is possible - see linked blog post.
2. Yes, it will time out. At least, this is what I experienced an issue when I tried to establish a MongoDB-connection outside the function handler with Provisioned Concurrency configured.
3. I can't really help you with that one...

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently added top level await support in **node14 and newer lambdas**: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-node-js-es-modules-and-top-level-await-in-aws-lambda/ . Using this you can simply make the init phase wait by using top level await like so:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

console.log("start init");
await sleep(1000);
console.log("end init");

export const handler = async (event) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
};
```

This works great if you are using ES modules. If for some reason you are stuck using commonjs (e.g. because your tooling like jest or ts-node doesn't yet fully support ES modules) then you can make your commonjs module look like an es module by making it export a Promise that waits on your initialization rather than exporting an object. Like so:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const main = async () => {
    console.log("start init");
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log("end init");

    const handler = async (event) => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
        };
    };
    return { handler };
};

# note we aren't exporting main here, but rather the result 
# of calling main() which is a promise resolving to {handler}:
module.exports = main();
```